# Why am I getting too many deprecated warnings while using Keras with TF backend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using TF 1.14 but every now and then I keep getting a lot of warnings. Is there some implication of these. If so is there any way to fix it or should I just ignore and carry on?
Example - "The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead."

Comment: Did you try following the instructions from the warning message? If so, what happened?

Comment: I am using Keras as a wrapper around TF. I am somewhat unfamiliar with TF so I haven't tried to tinker with it. But the point is I am getting this warning in a lot of Keras functions.